# How to use one model for different views and presenter in android?

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-mvp

I try to learn programming with design patterns. At the moment I try to build an android-app with the model-view-presenter pattern and I have problems to find out, how to design the classes when I have different views and presenter, which use the same model.

In my case I have view1 and presenter1, which manage the user input. This input goe's to the model and will be saved there.

Then I have view2 and presenter2, which should take the user input from the model and display it.

I figured out how to combine everthing (with interfaces etc.) when I have 1-1-1(view1-presenter1-model1). But I can't find out how to manage everthing when I have more than one view and presenter, which communicate with the same model.

The MainActivity represents the first View in my example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ContractMain.IViewMain {

private PresenterMain presenterMain;
private Button saveButton;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveButtonClicked(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    presenterMain = new PresenterMain(this);
}

@Override
public void saveButtonClicked(String input) {
    presenterMain.onSaveButtonClicked(input);
}
```

}

This would be the Presenter for the first View:

```
public class PresenterMain implements ContractMain.IPresenterMain {

ContractMain.IViewMain iViewMain;
Model model;

public PresenterMain(ContractMain.IViewMain iViewMain){
    this.iViewMain = iViewMain;
    model = new Model(this);
}

@Override
public void onSaveButtonClicked(String input) {
    if(!input.equals("")){
        model.saveInput(input);
    }
}
```

}

This would be the model:

```
public class Model implements IModel{

ContractMain.IPresenterMain iPresenterMain;

ArrayList<String> textInputContainer;

public Model(ContractMain.IPresenterMain iPresenterMain){
    this.iPresenterMain = iPresenterMain;
    textInputContainer = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public void saveInput(String input) {
    textInputContainer.add(input);
}

@Override
public String getInput(int index) {
    return textInputContainer.get(index);
}
```

}

This would be the second View:

```
public class View2 extends AppCompatActivity implements Contract2.IView2{

TextView textView;

Presenter2 presenter2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view2);

    textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    presenter2 = new Presenter2(this);
}

@Override
public void showData(String data) {
    textView.setText(data);
}
```

}

And finally this would be the presenter for the second view. Here I don't know how to reference the model to get the data, which I passed from the first view:

```
public class Presenter2 implements Contract2.IPresenter2{

Contract2.IView2 iView2;

public Presenter2(Contract2.IView2 iView2){
    this.iView2 = iView2;
}

@Override
public void onShowDataClicked() {
    String s = null;
    //Here i need to get the data from the model, save it in s and
    // send it to view2

    iView2.showData(s);
}
```

}

Comment: I downvote because it’s hard to answer a programming question without code : http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Sorry, first time here. I had to figure out how to post code.

Answer (score 0):

The model is an object of your business logic, for example user, or car or the business logic you need. The model is not dependent on the view or presenter, in fact the presenter can use more than one model to perform his operations and tell the view what to paint on it.

Therefore, the presenter can share a model, in fact it is normal for the models to be used in several presenters.

Comment: Ok , thanks for your answer. Do you know how to achieve that two presenter use the same model? Presenter1 already has an instance of model. How can I reference to the same model from Presenter2?